# UI automation SPY tool not detecting key press events

Tags: testing, automation, spy

UI automation SPY generating script for mouse click events and not detecting any keyboard and scroll events.

Comment: Do you mean Spy++? Or another Spy tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mouse click event or keyboard event or scroll event in UI Automation. You need Spy++ which detects Win32 messages. 
If you want to make a second try with UI Automation you can also try Automation Spy:
http://automationspy.freecluster.eu/ 
In the left tree select the window where you want to capture events and use the events green button on the top of the application.

Comment: Here is a list of events in UI Automation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-events-overview